# Projective limit of coverings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a path-connected, semilocally simply connected space.
Let $\tilde X$ be its universal convering and $\Gamma$ the group of deck transformations. Let $(\Gamma_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ be a family of subgroups, closed under finite intersections, such that $\bigcap_{\alpha\in A}\Gamma_\alpha=\{1\}$. Let $X_\alpha=\Gamma_\alpha\backslash \tilde X$ the corresponding covering space and let $\Omega$ be the projective limit over all $X_\alpha$.
If I'm not mistaken, this space is, as a set, the same as $\tilde X$, only equipped with a different topology.

My question is, whether such a space has been investigated anywhere and what is known about it and its topological invariants like homology and homtopy groups.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the  underlying set is the same.  For example say we take the circle and $\Gamma_n = n \mathbb Z$ for all $n \neq 0 \in \mathbb Z$.  Then it seems that your space fibers over the circle, but has $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ as its fiber. This is a sort of pro-etale cover of the circle.    In general, if you take the set of all finite index subgroups, you get something like the profinite completion of your space.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by saying that these types of maps $\Omega\to X$ are pretty well-understood even beyond spaces $X$ that admit simply connected covering spaces. Every inverse limit of covering maps (over any space) is a Hurewicz fibration with the unique path-lifting property. This class of fibrations is studied in Spanier's Algebraic Topology book. I am aware of [some ongoing research](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.02108) about the geometry of inverse limits of covering maps the focuses on the subtleties around this kind of construction.

Imposing the standard litany of conditions that make a space ``nice" enough to have a universal cover doesn't help. Let's assume that $X$ is path-connected, locally path-connected, and semilocally simply connected so that $X$ has a simply connected covering $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$. Let's say $q:\Omega\to X$ is your inverse limit of covering maps. There is a canonical continuous injection $f:\widetilde{X}\to\Omega=\varprojlim_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ such that $q\circ f=p$. You can construct $f$ and verify that it is injective using the lifting properties of the covering maps $X_{\alpha}\to X$ and the universal property of the limit. An inverse limit of path-connected and locally path-connected spaces need not have either property and this is exactly what will happen here. Consider what happens to the fibers. If the spaces $X_{\alpha}$ do not stabilize to $\widetilde{X}$, then $\Omega$ will not be homeomorphic to $\widetilde{X}$ because the fibers of $\Omega\to X$ will be a non-trivial inverse limit of discrete spaces (the fibers of the maps $X_{\alpha}\to X$). However, all fibers of $\widetilde{X}$ are discrete.

However, $f$ is guaranteed to map $\widetilde{X}$ onto a path component of $\Omega$, call it $\widetilde{\Omega}=f(\widetilde{X})$. Moreover, $f:\widetilde{X}\to \widetilde{\Omega}$ is a continuous bijection, which is also a weak homotopy equivalence. This answers your question: **the path-components of $\Omega$ are weakly homotopy equivalent to $\widetilde{X}$.** The difference is purely topological: $\widetilde{X}$ is the ``[locally path coreflection](https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/10/11/the-locally-path-connected-coreflection/)" of $\widetilde{\Omega}$. In particular, $f:\widetilde{X}\to \widetilde{\Omega}$ is a homeomorphism if and only if $\widetilde{\Omega}$ (equivalently $\Omega$) is locally path connected.

Considering that answer, it becomes clear that the utility of $\Omega$ lies outside of spaces with a universal cover. Notice that you don't need for $X$ to admit a universal covering space to construct $\Omega$. You just need enough covering maps over $X$ to distinguish all of the elements of $\pi_1(X)$ from the identity. For instance, if $X$ is the Hawaiian earring or Menger cube, then $\Omega$ as you describe it still exists. Again, inverse limits of path-connected spaces aren't typically path connected. However, the path-components of $\Omega$ are all simply connected. If you pick one, say $\widetilde{\Omega}$, then the restriction $\widetilde{\Omega}\to X$ may not be a true covering map because it may not be locally trivial and $\widetilde{\Omega}$ may not be locally path connected. However,

- $\widetilde{\Omega}\to X$ has all of the same lifting properties as a covering map
- $\pi_1(X)$ acts freely and transitively on the fibers of $\widetilde{\Omega}\to X$

In this way, $\widetilde{\Omega}\to X$ serves as a one of a handful of different kinds of "generalized" covering maps.